# Android серверная часть

Tags: android, backend

Использую в своем проекте Firebase и столкнулся с проблемами, а точнее его ограничениями. Не могу реализовать таймер (на стороне сервера), так как Firebase вообще на это не рассчитан. Теперь встает вопрос вопрос, кардинально менять серверную часть приложения или попытаться прикрутить что-то еще. В Firebase мне понравилась регистрация и облачный сервер, так все легко реализуется без каких-либо настроек, но ограниченный функционал все тормозит. Не могли бы вы, опытные разработчики, подсказать как мне быть в данной ситуации? Какой вектор развития взять и есть ли что-то универсальное?

Comment: Не понятна постановка задачи. Зачем вам таймер, что он должен делать?

Comment: @dmtr таймер используется следующим образом. Пользователь выбирает задачу, запускается таймер с определенным временем, исходя из выбранной задачи. По истечению времени что-то происходит. Ну вот в общих чертах цель моего таймера. И все это должно выполняться сервером, чтобы пользователь не мог менять время.

Comment: Почему нельзя реализовать таймер в приложении без пользовательского доступа к UI?

Comment: @dmtr а почему можно? Ведь на стороне сервера это будет безопаснее.

Comment: @dmtr сорри за оффтоп, но это был вопрос с подвохом? Просто возможно я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: Я просто не совсем понимаю какой безопасности вы хотите достичь. Если firebase не даёт вам нужного функционала, варианта два, которых я вижу: 1) реализовать внутри приложения. 2) запускать на отдельном сервере и ждать коллбека по окончанию действия таймера

Comment: @dmtr, просто я бы хотел, чтобы пользователь никак не мог повлиять на таймер. И когда юзер выходит из приложения то таймер не сбрасывается или останавливается. Я посчитал, что сервер отлично с этим справится. Но firebase не предоставляет текущее серверное время и не дает взаимодействовать с ним.